# Why does the root motion animation make the prefab move in the opposite direction?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

So basically I want to make a prefab (a cat) climb a wall, I wanna do it with basic root motion animation. Since I am new with unity and is my first time doing this I decided that I need to do a little bit of testing without any complicated animations, that being said, I made a simple animation, just moving the cat prefab, in the animation clip, the cat is moving on the +z axis.

HOWEVER, when I check the "root motion" check box and I click "Generate root motion curves" , instead of moving on the +z axis the cat is now moving on the -z axis, even if the cat is animated to move on the +z axis. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please do not ask questions with everything in bold. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your model is using different axys coordinates than Unity's. Blender for example has that problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, That problem was that I did not use in the animation the rotation, I used ONLY  the position, ,if you use the rotation in the animation it's ok ,also the sacel should be the original scale.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I only used the position of the object in the unity animation, using the position PLUS the rotation will fix the problem.